# Flatpickr -- How To Swipe Through Each Month?

Tags: flatpickr

I know there are next and previous arrows to cycle through the months. However, has anyone found a way to "swipe" to either a previous or next month with [flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/)? By "swipe" I am referring to either a click and drag to the next / previous month or of course on a mobile device a touch and drag.

Answer (score 0):

The flatpickr instance exposes the [`changeMonth(monthNum)`](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#changemonth-monthnum-is-offset-true) method that can be used to switch between months.

I used [hammerjs](https://hammerjs.github.io/) to handle the swipe gestures. You can access the `innerContainer` of the picker via the picker instance after the picker is ready and hook to the `swipeleft` and `swiperight` events.

```
let hammertime = new Hammer(pickerInstance.innerContainer);
hammertime.on('swipeleft', () => pickerInstance.changeMonth(1));
hammertime.on('swiperight', () => pickerInstance.changeMonth(-1));
```